# error Unrecognized database format in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dbf, oledbconnection

I have an error using a dbf/dbase database.

I want to create a combo box with values from the `CPN` column in my database, and I only want to display data where the `QOH` column is not zero or blank.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
    {
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0",
        .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))
    }
      
Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "dBase IV") 'I added this code but still error'
Dim dt = New DataTable()
Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select CPN,ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS FROM IFG WHERE QOH > 0", Builder.ToString)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
End Using
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
'ADD CODE FOR COMBOBOX
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
        dv.RowFilter = String.Format("ITM  LIKE '%{0}%'", ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dv

    End Sub
```

I see these errors:

[image: error in debug]

[image: error in debug-2]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I added this code ("Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "dBase IV") but still error (is not valid path).

Comment: I've managed to remove the error but I haven't succeeded in making sql not to display blanks and the value 0 in the qoh column and creating a combobox to filter the datagridview from the ITM column

Comment: I've managed to make the sql code not display blank and value 0 and I haven't succeeded in generating the code for the combobox filter in datagridview

Comment: What did you do to remove the error? How has the code changed?

Comment: I added this code
"Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "dBase IV")"
,I removed "DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),IFG.DBF)" to "DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.Desktop))". for error problems

Comment: Also, is Jet 4.0 _really_ the correct provider for dbf/dbase? I thought Jet 4 was the pre-2007 Access format?

Comment: but I haven't been able to filter the datagridview to the combobox

Comment: one more thing is it possible to make a checkbox for this code "WHERE QOH > 0"

Comment: dear mr. Joel Coehoorn,my goal is to use Jet 4.0 because I use windows 64 bit and other users who windows 32 bit can also use. so my answer is correct using Jet 4.0 and do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/ They also provide a link for help in connecting.

Comment: To communicate with a commenter, start with the @ sign followed by the name exactly as it appears. They will get a notice; otherwise they may never see your comment.

Comment: @Mary , for connection problems no problem anymore. The problem now is I want to do a checkbox with the code "WHERE QOH > 0" and I want to filter the datagridview with a combobox in the ITM column

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question. Set up how you are connecting and what data you have received. Then show what the combobox would contain and what criteria you need to filter by.

Comment: @Mary, for the row filter combobox I don't need to create a new question because it's already in the description and I've added the code for the combobox for the filter but it doesn't appear in the form, maybe there is something wrong in my code?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @Mary, I tried in combobox it doesn't show up